# kubernetes master and worker nodes getting different ip range

Tags: docker, kubernetes, overlay

I have setup a local kubernetes cluster, using vagrant. Have assigned 2 nw interfaces for each vagrant box public and private.

kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   
OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kubemaster   Ready    master   14h   v1.12.2   192.168.33.10   <none>        
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.4.0-137-generic   docker://17.3.2
kubenode2    Ready    <none>   14h   v1.12.2   10.0.2.15       <none>        
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.4.0-138-generic   docker://17.3.2
```

While initiating kubeadm on master, i ran ip advertise and gave ip as 192.168.33.10 of master.

My reall issue was i am not able to login to any pod.

```
kubectl exec -ti web /bin/bash
```

> error: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist

Answer (score 2):

It's because vagrant, in its default configuration, will have a NAT `public_network`, usually eth0, and then any additional network interfaces -- such as what is likely a host-only interface on 192.168.33.10

You need to change the kubelet configuration -- and possibly your CNI provider -- to bind and advertise the IP address of `kubenode2` that's in a subnet your machine can reach. Unidirectional traffic from `kubenode2` can likely reach `kubemaster` over the NAT IP, but almost by definition your machine cannot reach anything behind the NAT IP, thus the connection failure when trying to reach the kubelet port